# Image height as parent div height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have flexbox with few elemenets, for example paragraph and image. I would like to ignore image height when flexbox height is calculated. I want to image height be equal to max height of others elemenets in div

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  background-color: pink;
}

p{  
  width: 200px;
}

img{
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the height of the shared container to adjust to the text content?

Comment: `img{
  height: 100%; width : 100%;
}`

Comment: Yes, I want the height of the shared container to adjust to the text content in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image as a `background` instead of inline the only downside might be that you will have to give it a defined `width` but if this is not a problem in your case I would recommend doing it like this.

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  background-color: pink;
}

.image-wrapper {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300.png/');
  width: 200px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

p{  
  width: 200px;
}

img{
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be problematic because I may not know the dimensions and aspect ratio of the image and I want to keep the proportions

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
img{
display: flex
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it